# Was she a murderer?

Tags: plot-explanation, decision-to-leave

One of the characteristics of Park Chan-wook's lyrical movie [Decision To leave](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12477480/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) is that a great deal of what we see on screen is not what is happening, but what someone is *imagining* is happening.

This is an interesting cinematic choice, if very confusing on first viewing as there is no cinematic hint of which scenes are which. This can create some confusion about what actually happened.

First we see Seo-rae as a murder suspect for the death of her husband, but one the detective seems to have some attraction to. Then her alibi seems to exonerate her. Then, later, the detective comes across some new evidence that seems to confirm she *could* have committed the murder, which he hides.

A couple of years later after the insomniac detective has moved to a new much quieter town, he encounters Seo-rae again with a new husband. Then the new husband is brutally killed and the detective has to investigate this (the first murder for some time in the new town). Again, she is a suspect. Again, there is some circumstantial evidence that points towards her guilt. She appears to be manipulating the detective again exploiting his attraction to her.

But as the plot plays out, it looks like she was not the guilty party and another person confesses, quite plausibly. So Seo-rae's suspicious behaviour seems to have another explanation. And there is quite a lot of shenanigans about phone evidence relating to both murders.

But the nature of what we see, confusing us as to whether what is seen on screen is imagined or real, adds an extra layer of obscurity to what actually happened.

By the somewhat shocking and surprising end, I was left completely unsure about what happened.

So was Seo-rae a murderer? And which murder(s) was she guilty of?